# oData Date format with Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, date, jackson

I want jackson to parse date to the following format:

```
/Date(1413072000000)/
```

How can I do that with Jackson ObjectMapper? I tried setDateFormat and SimpleDateFormat, but inside that method I couldn't set miliseconds to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own DateFormat, like that:

```
public class MyDateFormat extends DateFormat {

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition fieldPosition) {
        return toAppendTo.append(String.format("/Date(%d)/", date.getTime()));
    }

    @Override
    public Date parse(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        return new MyDateFormat();
    }
}
```

And set the instance of MyDateFormat to ObjectMapper with:

```
mapper.setDateFormat(new MyDateFormat());
```

In MyDateFormat class there is added clone() overriden, because Jackson needs to clone our format in case of concurrency issues.

Comment: I tested that for mapper.writeValueAsString(new Date());